# Does the metafor package report adjusted R^2 or just normal R^2?

Tags: r, metafor

I am conducting a meta-analysis using the metafor package in R. Comparing models using `anova()` function, I can see the R^2.

```
fit1 <- rma(data = dat, yi, vi, mods = fix1)
fit2 <- rma(data = dat, yi, vi, mods = fix1 + fix2)
anova(fit1, fit2)
```

Is this adjusted R-square or just a normal R-square?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation provided in the `metafor` package. 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf

For the function `anova.rma`:

> R2
>
> > amount of (residual) heterogeneity in the reduced model that is accounted for
> >     in the full model (in percent). NA for fixed-effects models, if the amount of
> >     heterogeneity in the reduced model is equal to zero, or for "rma.mv" objects.
> >     This can be regarded as a pseudo R2
> >     statistic (Raudenbush, 2009). Note that the
> >     value may not be very accurate unless k is large (Lopez-Lopez et al., 2014).

Comment: Thank you very much, Amar. I will read the metafor's documentation and Raudenbush (2009).